# Python API call JSON to CSV iteration overwriting data

Tags: python, json, csv, append, overwrite

New to Python...trying to perform an API call and output the data to CSV.

Works fine for a single variable being passed but **when I parse through a list the last item in the list is the only output I receive**.

Looking to find the best way to approach this. Not sure if it's just an issue of logic or I need to find a way to consistently append to the file and remove results when it's rerun.

```
    list = open(infile, "r")
    print("-------------Attempting to Query Data----------------")
    for item in list: 
        try:
            if inp == 1:
                eval_string = "&value=" + item
            elif inp == 2:
                eval_string = "&value__regexp=.*." + item + "*"
            else:
                print("Invalid input!")
            result = requests.get(url + "api_key=" + api + "&username=" + user + eval_string + "&limit=" + str(limit) + "&status=" + status)
            data = result.json()
            if result.status_code == 200:
                with open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as data_file:
                    writer = csv.writer(data_file)
                    count = 0
                    for obj in data['objects']:
                        if count == 0:
                            header = 'value', 'confidence', 'type', 'source', 'date', 'status'
                            writer.writerow(header)
                            count += 1
                        writer.writerow([obj['value'], obj['confidence'], obj['type'], obj['source'], obj['date'], obj['status']])
            else:
                print("-------------Failed to connect - check API config info or that site is up----------------")
        except OSError:
            print("Failed to query.")
    print("-------------Results returned in " + outfile + "----------------")
```

Comment: `open(mode="w")` will wipe the contents of the file, that might be it. As an aside, what's the type of `obj`, and what do its contents look like? In the `writer.writerow()` are you using every single key?

Comment: Hi. So this is a json object from the API call and I'm only writing certain values from the object. I could probably get away with wiping the contents when the script is initially ran and then appending the results in the loop, but I wanted to see if there was a better approach.  thank you